# Goroutines (cgo): unexplained OS thread spawns when using goroutines

Tags: multithreading, go, cgo

I am using go to parallelize 2d convolutions where the convolution (implemented in go) is happening in a c-archive included in a C binary (where the go code is called). No calls are made from the go code to any c function

Before spawning goroutines, all matrixes are loaded into memory by the c code and all goroutines access it through the shared memory.

I use the GOMAXPROCS-1 to decide how many go routines to spawn and each routine is assigned a ID. The goroutines are assigned rows of the matrix based on their ID in a striped fashion. The go routines are locked to a OS thread when spawned and release the thread once finished.

e.g. 
if GOMAXPROCS is set to 4, goroutine 0 takes row 0, 4, 8, 12 etc and goroutine 1 takes row 1, 5, 9, 13 and so on.

My issue is that when GOMAXPROCS is set to 4, go spawns **11 OS threads**

htop and atop:
[image]

My understanding is that these OS threads are spawned because the scheduler is trying to make sure that there are always threads available that are not blocked.

There is no I/O or system calls happening after the goroutines have been spawned so I don't understand why the scheduler is creating all these processes or what is blocking the threads.

The number of threads being spawned is slowing down the execution when executing with GOMAXPROCS >=20 on a machine with 40 cores

Why is the scheduler spawning all these threads?
How can I debug where/how the routines are being blocked?

[Source code](https://github.com/Sigurthorb/OpenMPvsGoroutines-Convolutions/blob/master/ConvolutionLibrary/go/main.go)

Comment: It's hard to say how many you should expect without an example, but all C calls are blocking and on a different stack, so they must happen in a different thread.

Comment: Added link to source. Do you mean that calls to C.float and C.uchar are blocking as well or calls to my own C functions? I am not calling any custom C functions from my go code

Comment: No, `C.float` and `C.uchar` are types, not callable functions. You said the convolution is happening in a `c-archive included in a C binary.`, so I assumed you were calling into that with cgo, though you're correct that your example here has no cgo calls. I would start by removing the `LockOSThread` calls (you can't use thread-local storage in Go, so there's no reason to call it), then check any other locations where you might be making cgo calls.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I Updated description to make that clear that no c functions are called from the go code. By removing the LockOSThread, fewer threads are created (7 instead of 11) but the execution is slower by a few seconds (from 190 seconds without locking down to 180 seconds with locking). Going to try to reduce casting with C.float/C.uchar as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> GOMAXPROCS limits the number of threads running
> Go code, but cgo calls do not count as Go code, so
> you can still see multiple threads with GOMAXPROCS=1.

- https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/8Tdb-aCeYFY?pli=1